# How to deal with dogs dental issues?

Tags: dogs, dental-care, veterinarian

My girlfriend has a 6 year old Chihuahua/Pug named Willow.

She has HORRIBLE breathe! The worst I have ever smelled in a dog. I always said "this is not normal, go get this checked out", and my girlfriend said that vet said she is ok.

Now Willow is sick and lethargic. She took her to the vet, and they are not certain what is wrong so they gave her antibiotics....and they also said "Her front teeth may need to be extracted".

First off, how do you go from "being ok" to "needing to be extracted"??

Is this vet doing a sub par job? Should I recommend she find a new vet?

Secondly, what step can be taken to improve Willows dental hygiene and health? She is a very healthy and happy dog otherwise, and I would hate for this to become a serious issue for her!

Comment: can you post pictures of your dogs teeth? From the front to all the way in the back?